# TexBox wont enable catches exception of type "Object Reference not set to an instance"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, textbox

I am working on a project wrote in Visual Basic. I have a check Box and e TextBox and i want to enable the TextBox when the checkbox is checked.
This is my code:

```
    Public Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged

    Dim CheckBox3 As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    convertToStaff = CheckBox3.Checked

    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            test.Enabled = True
            convertToStaff = CheckBox3.Checked
            Session("convertToStaff") = convertToStaff
        End If

End Sub
```

End here is my front end code

```
  <td style="width:100px; ">Staff:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp                                                                          


  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked="false" 
   AutoPostBack="True"   

    OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" />

     </td>
      <td style="width:200px; ">


      <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" class="text_box" 
       Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>

      </telerik:RadTextBox>

             </td>
```

For some reasons i am not understanding the row `test.Enabled = True` will throw an exception of type Object Reference not set to an instance

Any idea where i am doing wrong?

Comment: you don't set _your_ textbox enabled, but you instantiate a complete new textbox (`Dim RadTextBox2 As New RadTextBox`)  and set this enabled. Where do you store a reference to the textbox you actually want to enable?

Comment: @RenéVogt if i remove Dim RadTextBox2 As New RadTextBox and declare it  Dim RadTextBox2 As RadTextBox in the begining of the file it stops debugin in the RadTextBox2.Enabled = True row. i am not getting what do you mean by store a reference to the textbox ?

Comment: Can you post your front-end? You are obviously creating a new textbox, and enabling it, but you're not binding it to the front-end at all.  Are you wanting this textbox to show up on the front-end after a checkbox is checked?

Comment: I see a call to `Session` are you sure you are not using asp.net or anything else? I ask this as well because `RadTextBox` is a common web control by Telerik...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yes i am using asp,net and telerik controls, i tried even with not telerik but the issue is the same. i think there is somenthin in the way i declare the textbox or similar

Comment: @JohnPete22 i updated my question so you can see even the front end code. i want my textBox to enable in the front end when the user checks the check box

Comment: @Juli Delete the line `Dim RadTextBox2 As New RadTextBox`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i already did reading the suggestions above, but this way when trying to execute RadTextBox2.Enabled = True for some reasons it stops debugging and does nothing to my textbox

Comment: @Juli Did you remember to do a rebuild? I'm forever saving a code file I've just worked on and then wonder why the changes don't show up.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes i did and redid. I do not know why such a simple thing should has to cause so much trouble.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Anyway i putted my code in a try catch and saw that the enabled row throws an exception of type Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Juli If you enable [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#conditions) for the whole project, does it show problems that you can correct? It is possible (fingers crossed) that it will work after that.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to the designer screen.

2- Select your rad textbox by clicking on it.

3- In the *Properties* window, loot up the name of your textbox (It's probably something like *TextBox1* or *RadTextBox1*). Note it somewhere or copy it with ctrl+c

4- Go back to your code. When you *Dim* a rad textbox, you create a radtextbox. That's not how you use a control. Wat you want it to use the textbox which name you just noted. So, instead of your earlier code snippet, try this:

```
If convertToStaff = True Then
    TheNameOfTheTextBoxYouNotedEarlier.Enabled = True

    Session("convertToStaff") = convertToStaff
End If
```

This will "target" the textbox that you created in your form designer, which is the one you can see on your screen.

Comment: by name i think you mean the id? i tried                                  If convertToStaff = True Then
Dim test As TextBox                                               test.Enabled = True
            Session("convertToStaff") = convertToStaff
        End If                                                                                       if this is what you meant, but is not working,when executing test.Enabled = True stops debugin and does nothing. test is the id of my textbox

Comment: *mean. I mean.

When you _Dim_ the textbox inside your Sub, you create a new textbox. You cannot see it, first because you haven't placed it on the form, and second because it's like a local variable: it's contained inside the scope of the Sub and disappear with it. It takes a fraction of a second to your computer to run the Sub; even if you did place the new textbox on the form programatically, it wouldn't show to your slow human eyes.

If you can see your code but not the form designer, try hitting shift+F7. Right click on the desired control and see _Properties_. You'll get it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CI9Zoq4 i asked you because i do not have a property named name only ID, and in C# where i mostly work we target the element by ID.  Anyway thank you. I already tried your code and as i told for some reason it gets me out of debug when trying to execute the enable row

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be equivalent. The mistake seems to me that you still _Dim_ your textbox. Don't do that, it already exist. When you write _Dim test as TextBox_, you create a textbox named "test", and you use this one by default because it's closer to the scope of the Sub. That's why it does nothing. Instead, use _test.Enabled = True_ without the _Dim_, and you'll access the TextBox of the Form (and will be able to claim victory!)

Comment: i am not dim-ing it anymore as you suggested, i also updated the code in my question. The thing is that now the TextBox.Enabled = True row is throwing an exception of type "Object Reference not set to an instance"

Answer (score 0):

I created some basic code to see if this helps you.

Front-end

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Check me"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="RadTextBox2" Width="100%" runat="server" CssClass="text_box" Enabled="false"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind

```
Partial Class _StackOverflowTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub CheckBox3_CheckChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox3.Checked Then
            RadTextBox2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, i do not see much difference from my code, but i tried anyway. For some reasons when executing RadTextBox2.Enabled = True it gets me out of debug and doing nothing to my textBox

Comment: One thing, I removed the OnSelectionChanged from the front-end and just handled it in the code-behind only.  You might want to think about adding a tag to #telerik in your post to see if someone can add some knowledge with that.  I had assumed it was like regular asp<TextBoxes>.  By the way, this code I posted works fine and enables the Textbox on PostBack.

Comment: Edit: I had said OnSelectioChanged....I meant to say OnCheckedChanged.  Remove that from the front-end and in the code-behind, keep the "Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged"

Comment: in my case does not enter in the fuction if do not use in front end. Anyway i putted my code in a try catch and saw that the enabled row throws an exception of type Object reference not set to an instance of an object.